# create subfolders in firebase Folder

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an Android file management application where users can upload, download, and organize files into folders. Currently, I have implemented basic file and folder functionalities. Now, I want to extend the application to support nested folders, allowing users to create folders inside other folders.

I use firebase database and java language and android studio

```
public void createFolder() {
    // Create a Dialog object
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

    // Set the content view of the dialog by inflating folder_dialog.xml
    View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.folder_dialog, null);
    dialog.setContentView(dialogView);

    // Now, you can find and use the views inside the dialogView
    EditText folderNameEditText = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.FolderName);
    Button createFolderBtn = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.CreateFolderBtn);

    // Set click listener for the create folder button
    createFolderBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        String folderName = folderNameEditText.getText().toString().trim();

        // Perform folder creation logic here
        if (!folderName.isEmpty()) {
            DatabaseReference foldersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("folders").child(currentUserId);

            // Generate a unique key for the folder
            String folderId = foldersRef.push().getKey();

            // Store folder metadata in the Realtime Database
            FolderMetadata folderMetadata = new FolderMetadata(folderId, folderName);

            // Save folder metadata using the unique key
            foldersRef.child(folderId).setValue(folderMetadata)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> {
                        // Folder created successfully
                        StyleableToast.makeText(FolderActivity.this, "Folder created successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, R.style.mytoast).show();
                        dialog.dismiss(); // Dismiss the dialog after creating the folder
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                        // Folder creation failed
                        StyleableToast.makeText(FolderActivity.this, "Folder creation failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, R.style.mytoast).show();
                    });
        } else {
            folderNameEditText.setError("Please enter a folder name");
        }
    });

    // Show the dialog
    dialog.show();
}
```

I wrote these codes when I wanted to create a folder inside the main account of the user, that is, in the root, but now I do not know how I can get the parent Folder Id so that I can create folders inside each other.

In the beginning, I created a new class called the FolderActivity so that I could display the files and folders inside the folder I created.

The CreateFolder method that I had previously created was on the Home class , so I made an object so that I could use it, but when I press the Create Folder button, it takes me out of the page and takes me to the Home page, so I copied the Create Folder method and wrote it in the FolderActivity class, and now when I press the Create Folder button. A dialog box appears from which I enter the name of the folder. When I create and write the name of the folder, it saves it in the user’s main folder, that is, in the root folder and not in the folder that I clicked on.

Comment: Please tell in the subject of your post right away that they are Firebase folders.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Please respond using @AlexMamo